# how to access a multidimensional array in Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have a file that looks like this:

```
A:B:C
G:P:T
K:M:Q
...
```

I have loaded the file in an array `@letters`.

I need to retrieve each letter without the `:` and pass it as a parameter to another script that I call.

so

```
/bin/kish -x /home/whatever/testscript $letter[0 1] $letter[0 2] $letter[0 3]
```

then

```
/bin/kish -x /home/whatever/testscript $letter[1 1] $letter[1 2] $letter[1 3]
```

until end of array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: tried `split(":")`? [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: Don't fool yourself into thinking the first arg of `split` is a string. Use `split /:/`

Answer (score 1):

So first we need to build a multidimensional array, the best way I know to do this in Perl is using references:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $fh, "<", "data" );
my @rows;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @row = split(':', $line) ;
    push( @rows, \@row );
};
```

The `\` operator in `\@row` means that each element of the list `@rows` is actually a reference to another list `@row`. This allows for the sort of nested indexing which you seem to be seeking, like so:

```
`/bin/kish -x /home/whatever/testscript $rows[0]->[0] $rows[0]->[1] $rows[0]->[2]`
```

First we index into the list as usual (this is the "row" number). The arrow operator `->` dereferences the reference to the list, then we index into that dereferenced list with the appropriate "column" number

Comment: Loading the array worked well, thanks! I can print each element using:

Comment: Loading the array worked well, thanks! I can print each element using: foreach my $index (0..$#rows) { print "$rows[$index]->[0]\n";
print "$rows[$index]->[1]\n";
print "$rows[$index]->[2]\n"; but when I substituted the prints with exec (" /bin/ksh -x /home/blah/test1 $rows[$index]->[0] $rows[$index]->[1] $rows[$index]->[2]"); } it only executes the script for the 1st element and not the other. Any ideas. thanks!

Comment: you should use `system` and not `exec`

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($line=<FILEHANDLE>) {
    @letters=split(/\W+/,$line);
    system("/bin/kish -x /home/whatever/testscript $letters[0] $letters[1] $letters[2]");
}
```

You will need to open FILEHANDLE first. The while() loop (first) reads the file, one line at a time. The second takes the line, breaks it into chunks (non-alphanumeric characters [such as ":"] are used to define the breaks between the chunks). The system line runs the command itself. The last line "}" shows where the loop ends.